# Is learning Python over Java is preferable in future for automation testing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, manual-testing, test-automation-framework

Want to be master in automation..so please folks help me to achieved it.

I know core java basic which I used in automation testing Selenium web-driver (learning phase using it for past 2-3 months).
So does learning python will help? Or should I continue it java.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14142/i-want-to-learn-selenium-but-not-sure-about-the-language-i-need-to-learn-for-aut?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferable not, more benificial maybe. Knowing more programming languages might make you language agnostic. Picking up a third new popular language later will be so much easier. Most languages do not differ so much, but Python has some interesting concepts. Also it is known for being beginner friendly.

Still I would try to learn one language well.

With Selenium you test web applications, understanding how they work might be more important than a second language. So also do some HTML, css and JavaScript courses.

Comment: hey thanks Niels, will follow and so will have to be focused on Javascript for time being and explore more around automation...:) thanks for your support guys :)

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter.

If you want to "master" automation you will need so much more (knowledge) than being proficient with one programming language.

You will need many years to master automation skills. In that time, you will learn more than one language in advanced, if being "master" is really what you want to do.

Comment: thanks...for your suggestion and could you please mentioned some languages so that i can start contributing towards it...thanks :)

Comment: Sure!

But please remember that apart from language itself you'll need a lot of general automation experience and knowledge. Knowing the preferred language really help, but it's not everything.

You'll also need to gain great experience within:
{- Algorithms
- Building framework
- Probably everything around CI/CD/DevOps
- And so on}

Languages (Scripting, Hypertext Markup languages, Object Oriented and so on...) that you will probably need to know while mastering automation:
{- Java
- Python
- JavaScript
- Ruby
- HTML
- PHP}

Answer (score 0):

Automation in testing is more than scripting Selenium tests.

Knowing one programming language you can solve many other problems. For instance, knowing "only" Java I was able to solve problems like:

- automate tests for Web services
- create mocks for SAML authentication
- find random users for parallel tests so they do not overlap
- find random flights matching certain criteria for tests
- compare configurations in DBs between two environments
- create authentication libraries for other teams
- create tools to convert HTTP requests to curl commands

What are the problem you can solve in your team?